# Why is selected text not clearly identifiable in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, highlight, highlighting

I have a problem with the Visual Studio 2015 editor. I changed the background color to black. It is very hard to identify selected text, which becomes a problem while coding.

So I went to `Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors` and in the settings for `Text Editor` I changed the choices for the display item `Selected Text`. The `Item foreground` option cannot be changed. So I tried to change the `Item background` option to red. The sample displayed has a bright red background and yellow characters. This is not what I see on my screen: a dark background with a very faint reddish tint and white characters. The background is almost indistinguishable from the editor's overall pitch black background. Choosing other colors instead of red makes things worse: no tint is displayed around the characters.

Is there a way to make selected text clearly identifiable in VS 2015?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will keep you busy for a while.  Consider using readily available color schemes, like Tools > Options > Environment > General > Color theme = Dark.  Google "vs2015 dark color theme" for more.

Comment: I had already done Tools > Options > Environment > General > Color theme = Dark. There are only three options for Color theme: Blue, Dark, and Light.

Comment: I Googled "vs2015 dark color theme" and found the cool site `https://studiostyl.es/` (thanks for the suggestion). After importing settings for `WekeRoad Ink` I had a new theme on the editor. The background was not as black as I like. Selected text remained as difficult to spot as before, with a barely discernible blue tint. So I am still stuck.

Comment: If *four thousand* themes isn't enough then you'll be busy for a while.  But at least you have a decent start so you don't have to change all of the colors.  Don't forget to submit your theme to the site, it will no doubt be special.

Comment: You are right, four thousand was enough, although I did not go through all of them. I managed to find a nice theme (C# N Nice), modify it slightly and I am now very happy. Many thanks.